# Configuration error [driver not found: ] while creating a junit test in Intellij and using Play framework 2

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, junit4

I am trying to do unit tests, i am using junit and intellij and play framework 2.0.4.

My test is like this:

```
public class ModelsTest  {

@Test
public void retrieveUser(){
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Verkefni f = Verkefni.findProjectByVerkefniID(16);
            assertThat(f.getVerkefni_id()).isEqualTo(16);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And when i run it i get  the  following error:

```
Configuration error: Configuration error [Driver not found: [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:71)
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:258)
at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.play$api$db$BoneCPApi$$register(DB.scala:283)
at play.api.db.BoneCPApi...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.play$api$db$BoneCPApi$$register(DB.scala:281)
... 47 more
```

Do you guys have any idea what is wrong? i have an oracle driver under a directory called lib and in application.conf i call it like this:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is [deprecated](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=339971).

For Oracle 9i onwards you should use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver rather than oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver as Oracle have stated that oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is deprecated and support for this driver class will be discontinued in the next major release.

This means that your `application.conf` should look like this instead:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```